# Copy section from one INI file to another INI file

Tags: java, powershell, ini

I have two .ini files (ABC.ini and ABC1.ini) and ABC.ini will always be up to date. The ABC1.ini should have few sections similar to the first ini file so that this file will also be up to date. Now I want to know how can I copy the specific sections from one file to another. My sections will be like,
`[LINK.Server1....n.Mappings]`
`[LINK.Server1.....n]`
`[LINK.User(1.....n]`

I need to copy these sections from ABC.ini to ABC1.ini and these sections might exist in ABC1.ini file already so I would need to delete the existing content in ABC1.ini and replace the new content from ABC.in

Could you all please advise if this can be achieved using powershell/java. Any sample will help.

What I have done till now.

```
Write-Host "Reading parameters from 'parameters.ini' file...";
Get-Content "parameters.ini" | ForEach-Object -Begin {$settings=@{}} -Process {$store = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($store[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("#") -ne $True)) {$settings.Add($store[0], $store[1])}}


$Param1 = $settings.Get_Item("Param1")
$Param2 = $settings.Get_Item("Param2")
$Param3 = $settings.Get_Item("Param3")

# Displaying the parameters
Write-Host "Param1 value is: $Param1";
Write-Host "Param2 value is: $Param2";
Write-Host "Param3 value is: $Param3`n";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it can be achieved using powershell/java.

Comment: Can I get any sample code?

Comment: Maybe we're willing to if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) your question properly. For example: you're not really showing any effort you did into researching the problem.

Comment: Hello, I was able to take the file and get the content of each section. Updated in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Two ini files each with the key name

file1 name=John Ray
file2 name=John Doe

compare the two and if the key name doesn't match update file1

```
$File1 = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\User1\Temp\file1.ini
$File2 = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\User1\Temp\file2.ini

$Name1 = ($File1 | Select-String "name=").line
$Name2 = ($File2 | Select-String "name=").line

if ($Name1 -ne $Name2)
{
    $File1.replace($name1,$name2)
    Set-Content -Path C:\Users\User1\Temp\file1.ini -Value $File1
}
```

Comment: Hello Dave, Thanks for the answer. I don't want to compare two files as there will be additional entries in the first file, I want to put all the section starting with the code [LINK.Server(1....n).Mappings] [LINK.Server1.....n] [LINK.User1.....n] in the second file. I also need to delete all the sections starting with the above code to be removed in the second file before copying from the first file. Please let me know how I can achieve that. May be use some regular expression to find the pattern?

Comment: you need copy the contents of one on the ini files and post it in your question. I can't build a query if i don't know how your section ends or how many lines it has etc.

Comment: Hello Dave, Please see the sample content of the ini file, there could be many entries like this in the .ini file.[LINK.AppServer1]
Destination=
ProgId=
[LINK.AppServer2]
Destination=
ProgId=
[LINK.User1]
Test=TRUE
Name=ABC
[LINK.User2]
Test=TRUE
Name=DEF
[LINK.AppServer1.Mappings]
SYS=5T
[LINK.AppServer2.Mappings]
SYS=5H

Comment: Hello Dave, Did you get time to look into this? Thanks in advance! `[LINK.AppServer1]
Destination=
ProgId=
[LINK.AppServer2]
Destination=
ProgId=
[LINK.User1]
Test=TRUE
Name=ABC
[LINK.User2]
Test=TRUE
Name=DEF
[LINK.AppServer1.Mappings]
SYS=5T
[LINK.AppServer2.Mappings]
SYS=5H`